# Составление запроса с подсчетом в Mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, node.js, запрос, select

Я в работе с базами новичек и вот с чем не могу разобраться.
Есть вот такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`idCake` - это `id` тортика, который был продан. Мне нужно посчитать, сколько тортов с `id = 2` было продано в этом месяце, а сколько в предыдущем.

То есть мне нужно составить массив примерно такого вида:

```
[
 {
  id: 5, // id тортика 
  date: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40] // массив продаж по месяцам, то есть за янв. продано 40 шт., февраль 39 шт., март 10 и тд
 }
]
```

Возможно сделать такое сложение запросом к базе или нужно сделать несколько простых запросов и складывать уже на бэке или фронте?

Comment: Реляционные базы данных не работают или работают со скрипом с любым форматом данных, кроме двухмерного, поэтому такого рода агрегацию все равно придется делать на бэкенде. Однако, как ответили выше, получить двухмерную таблицу по месяцам не составляет нникакого труда, после чего надо будет всего лишь однократно вызывать `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно одним запросом к базе:

```
SELECT idCake, MONTH(Data), COUNT(idOrders)
FROM YourTable
WHERE idCake = 2
GROUP BY idCake, MONTH(Data)
```

`MONTH()` - получает месяц из даты (если нужно название месяца, то - `MONTHNAME()`);
`COUNT()` - считает количество заказов. Так как эта функция агрегирующая, необходима группировка;
`GROUP BY` - группируем сначала по `idCake`, потом по месяцу;

Если нужно посчитать для всех типов тортов, то нужно убрать строку `WHERE idCake = 2`.